# Add toolbar to embedded PDF file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pdf, pages, embedded

I have the code to embed a PDF file to a SharePoint 2013 page; however, the PDF is opened in full screen mode by default(as below), and the top ribbon is not shown unless you change the mode.

```
<object><embed src="https://communitie0Control%20Towers%20EMEA.pdf" height="850" width="1100"
 type="application/pdf"></embed></object>
```

[image]

I need to change the display style as belowv(with the ribbon displayed by default). Can you please help? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding the `#toolbar` tag to your embed source

```
<object><embed src="https://communitie0Control%20Towers%20EMEA.pdf#toolbar=1" height="850" width="1100" type="application/pdf"></embed></object>
```